# Deepin Installer won't start - stuck on black screen with single dash

Tags: system-installation, uefi, bootable, deepin

I have just bought an Asus Zenbook UX433FA, on which I want to install Deepin 15.8 as my only OS. I have followed the [installation guide](https://www.deepin.org/en/installation/) on the Deepin website, therefore creating a bootable USB device with a Deepin iso (tried 15.8, 15.7, and 15.4) from which I would later attempt booting up.

I also disabled *SecureBoot* and *FastStartup* in the BIOS setup.

However, when booting from the USB device, I get presented a black screen with a non-blinking white dash in the top-left corner instead of being shown the Deepin Installer---no matter what the Deepin iso version is.

I was nonetheless able to install Ubuntu 18.04 using the same method without any issue whatsoever, so this should be Deepin related.

Note that I tried by bootable USB drive on another laptop of mine and that the Deepin installer does start properly on it.

I am running out of ideas to fix this issue, any suggestion?